# Is there any other elegant way to fetch data from JSON and render it to DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a simple JSON file named contents.json and I fetch this data in my localhost using this Pure JavaScript code,so my question is there any better way to do this kind of data fetching.

**JavaScript**

```
function fetchData(){
    fetch('http://localhost:5500/proje/contents.json').then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data.Contents);
        const html = data.Contents
            .map(movie => {
                return `
                
                <div class="column">
                <img id="${movie.Title}"  src="${movie.Poster}" class="item img-2">
                <b class="text">${movie.Title}</b>
                </div>
                
                `
                
            }).join('');
        
        document.querySelector('#app').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',html); 
        
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: You should look into templates and slots usage. More information is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots. This will help reduce creating HTML from JS as string and inserting into DOM. Also, you will get style isolation if that's desirable.

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about the method there is async await it will look like this

```
async function fetchingData(){
let data= await fetch('http://localhost:5500/proje/contents.json').json(),
html = data.Contents.map(movie => {
            return `
            
            <div class="column">
            <img id="${movie.Title}"  src="${movie.Poster}" class="item img-2">
            <b class="text">${movie.Title}</b>
            </div>
            
            `
            
        }).join('');)
document.querySelector('#app').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',html); 
}
```

async tells the js engine that it will return a promise, but if you combine it with await, await makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result.
the function execution will pause on the line of await until the promise resolves, it is as simple as that.